# zig print float precision

Tags: zig

In zig it is possible to print float values in decimal notation by using "{d}". This will automatically print the value at full precision. Is there way to specify the number of digits? Either for each value, or as some kind of global setting?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

This will limit the number of digits after the decimal point, with rounding and zero-padding:

```
format(w, "{d:.1}", .{0.05}) == "0.1"
format(w, "{d:.3}", .{0.05}) == "0.050"
```

[More info](https://github.com/ziglang/zig/blob/d4e22e3eb668968fa30f25c382b97629902f0bf8/lib/std/fmt.zig#L32)